# Does Symfony 2 request object protect against sql injection

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, code-injection

Does using this class: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

as opposed to $_GET and $_POST project against sql injection.

I mostly use findby and findoneby but I do have a general search that I made that I'm worried about.

I'm using $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery("query") for the search.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use doctrine's built in methods or you write your own DQL statement using placeholders and parameters, you will not running into any risk.

Take a look at [this page](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/security.html)

In your specific case, as you didn't provide a real example, I cannot evaluate but I think that you are exposing your database to sql-injection.
A soution, ad I told you here, is to use query builder along with placeholders and parameters.